# emgu / opencv image complement unexpected output

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I'm not understanding the interaction of Image.Not and Image.AbsDiff.

1. load image (OK)
2. take it's complement (OK)
3. diff image w/itself (OK=all black)
4. diff complement with original (???? Shouldn't this be all white ???)

here's code :

```
var i0 = CvInvoke.Imread("myimage.jpg").ToImage<Gray,Byte>();
var not = i0.Not();
var diffself = i0.AbsDiff(i0);
var diffnot = i0.AbsDiff(not);
CvInvoke.Imshow(i0,not,diffself,diffnot);
```

[image: results of code shown]

Can somebody explain why the difference between an image and it's complement is an entirely new image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid question, as soon as I wrote it I saw the mistake.

Addition is reverse of subtraction. :)

```
//var diffnot = i0.AbsDiff(not);
var reverse = i0.Add(not);
CvInvoke.Imshow(i0,not,diffself,reverse);
```